# angular $http.get makes three successful requests but returns error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http

I have a strange intermittent problem with angular's `$http.get`.  When I call my rest service, I can see from Chrome Dev tools that the `GET` request is made and that it returns with **status 200**, but the response content is empty, and the failure callback is invoked with `error = null` and `status = 0`.  Further, for one call of `$http.get`, the GET request is made 3 times (each time returning 200 with empty content).

If I clear my cache and reload my application this error usually disappears, but then (sometimes, not always) returns the next time the app is loaded.

Here is how the request is made:

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url, {timeout: 15000})
            .success(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            })
            .error(function(error, status) {
                //report error.
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
    return deferred.promise;
```

And here is how http is set up:

```
vizApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-type'];
    }
]);
```

Comment: If it's resolving then it's not Angular. Check the response from the server by hitting the API endpoint directly in the browser.

Comment: Looks like server-side issue

Comment: Hitting the API endpoint directly results in a successful get - no problem.  I don't think the problem is on the server side.

Comment: Can you post your code to jsfiddle or plunker? Further more, you can try to open this get url in your browser to see what's the response in your page.